# How can I tell the MongoDB C# driver to store all Guids in string format?

Tags: mongodb, serialization, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm currently applying the `[BsonRepresentation(BsonType.String)]` attribute to all `Guid` properties in my domain models to have those properties serialized in string format. Besides being tiresome to do, that doesn't work out sometimes, e.g. with custom `Wrapper<T>` classes:

```
public class Wrapper<T>
{
    public T Value { get; set; }

    // Further properties / business logic ...
}
```

When `T` is `Guid`, the `Value` property will be stored as binary data of type `UuidLegacy` (as will any property of type `Guid` that's not decorated with the above attribute). However, I'd like all `Guid`s, including `Wrapper<Guid>.Value`, to be represented as a string in the database.

Is there any way to tell the MongoDB C# driver to store all `Guid`s in string format?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can be achieved using Conventions

Something along the lines of:

```
var myConventions = new ConventionProfile();
myConventions.SetSerializationOptionsConvention(
    new TypeRepresentationSerializationOptionsConvention(typeof (Guid), BsonType.String));

BsonClassMap.RegisterConventions(myConventions, t => t == typeof (MyClass));
```

This should go somewhere in your app startup.

You can read more about conventions here: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/CSharp+Driver+Serialization+Tutorial#CSharpDriverSerializationTutorial-Conventions

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to the `SetSerializationOptionsConvention` method, Alex! I changed the last line slightly to apply the convention to all classes: `BsonClassMap.RegisterConventions(myConventions, _ => true);`

Comment: No problem. Wasn't sure if it was a particular class, or all classes you wanted to map the convention to

Comment: Obsolete now but thanks for the pointer.  RegisterConventions is replaced with ConventionRegistry.Register

Answer (score 8):

An alternative to performing this globally without setting a `Convention` (which I believe is overkill given the *actual* question was effectively: "how can this be applied globally") can be done by simply calling one line of code:

```
BsonSerializer.RegisterSerializer(typeof(Guid), 
    new GuidSerializer(BsonType.String));
```

Just make sure this is the first thing that fires in terms of MongoDb's serialization configuration (even before class maps are registered, the same is true for the convention based solutions posted).

Personally I see this as a better solution than creating a convention with an 'always return true' predicate, that most seem to be suggesting. Conventions are great for more complex scenarios, and for grouping sets of serialization configurations, where the predicate is *actually* used, and multiple `Conventions` are bundled into a `ConventionPack`. But for simply applying a global serialization format, just keep it simple with the above line of code.

If you later decide you have a legitimate `Convention` that requires a variation of this rule, just register it in order to overwrite the global rule we have set, just as your `Convention` would overwrite the *default* global rule, which is set to have `Guid's` represented as `BsonType.Binary`. The net result then would be the global rule taking precedence, followed by the `Convention`, which will overwrite our custom global rule *only* in such cases where the custom `ConventionPack` is applicable (based on your custom predicate).

Answer (score 4):

While using conventions will work, pay attention to two important (and related) points:

1. The `filter` parameter is required, and if the filter is too general (for example: `t => true`), it can overwrite other registered conventions.
2. Be aware that the order of registered conventions is important, first register specific filters and after register general conventions.

Another option is to create a BSON Class Map for type Guid, which sets the representation to string:

```
if (!BsonClassMap.IsClassMapRegistered(typeof(Guid))) {
    BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<Guid>(cm => {
        cm.AutoMap();
        cm.Conventions.SetSerializationOptionsConvention(new  TypeRepresentationSerializationOptionsConvention(typeof(Guid), BsonType.String));
    });
}
```

This should be done before any reading/writing using BsonSerializer, otherwise the default Class Map will be created, and you wont be able to change the Class Map.

Comment: I'm receiving the following error when using this, I think i might be obsolete now.  "This class map was setup using an IConventionPack, part of the new conventions api. Use the ConventionPack property for access to the conventions."

Comment: I haven't used the latest version of the Mongo C# Driver, although I am aware of changes to the Convention API. There is a `ConventionPack` property on the `cm` parameter, which should be used instead.

Answer (score 4):

ConventionProfile was deprecated. If you don't want to apply the rule globally, but only for a specific class (this should go somewhere in your app startup):

```
var pack = new ConventionPack { new GuidAsStringRepresentationConvention () };
ConventionRegistry.Register("GuidAsString", pack, t => t == typeof (MyClass));

public class GuidAsStringRepresentationConvention : ConventionBase, IMemberMapConvention
    {
        public void Apply(BsonMemberMap memberMap)
        {
            if (memberMap.MemberType == typeof(Guid))
            {
                var serializer = memberMap.GetSerializer();
                var representationConfigurableSerializer = serializer as IRepresentationConfigurable;
                if (representationConfigurableSerializer != null)
                {
                    var reconfiguredSerializer = representationConfigurableSerializer.WithRepresentation(BsonType.String);
                    memberMap.SetSerializer(reconfiguredSerializer);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is the only one answer that worked for me. The other ones are obsolete.